# Motion Capture rig

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, motion-capture

I would like to understand this thing:

If i have a rig in blender, a simple rig witohut any constraint. Only bones parented each other like that

[image]

**Do i need to insert fk/ik, copy rotation/location and so on relations between bones**, like i was animating with keyframe, or **the motion capture system follows simply the human movement and don't need any constraint?**

Comment: If you are going to animate based purely on the mocap, NO. Then again there are so many differing rig setups / rest-poses in mocap data, that rigging a complex rig (eg rigify) then driving it with drivers/constraints (retargetting)  isn't a bad idea.